# Matching vulnerabilities with upstream versions

Tags: vulnerability-scanners, fingerprinting, fingerprint

How am I supposed to match vulnerabilities with services fingerprint, with string like these? Is there a public database to match these versions with original versions?

```
> 5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
> 5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.04.2
> 5.5.31-0+wheezy1
> 5.5.31-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
> 5.5.31-0ubuntu0.12.04.2
> 5.5.31-0ubuntu0.13.04.1
> 5.5.33-0+wheezy1
> 5.5.33-cll-lve
> 5.5.34-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
> 5.5.34-0ubuntu0.13.04.1
> 5.5.34-0ubuntu0.13.10.1
```

Thank you

Comment: Why do you not turns it into CPE?

Comment: Nmap can returns this version as fingerprint using `-sV`, but the easy way to deal with it is turns it into a CPE. So, you can compare with any database that uses (MITRE) CPE specification, such as NIST to assess vulnerability.